# How can I use assert_select in a Rails functional test to check for multiple elements of the same type, differing only by text?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, functional-testing, assertions

I have a Rails view that outputs HTML similar to this:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Keywords</h1>

    <h2>EN</h2>
    <h3>Accepted</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Foo</li>
    </ul>
    <h3>Rejected</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Bar</li>
    </ul>

    <h2>SV</h2>
    <h3>Accepted</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Föö</li>
    </ul>
    <h3>Rejected</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Bär</li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'd like to use `assert_select` to ensure that I have `<h2>` tags for each language:

```
languages.each do |language|
  assert_select 'body > h2', :text => language.upcase
end
```

But this fails:

```
<"DE"> expected but was
<"SV">.
<false> is not true.
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.1.2/lib/action_controller/assertions/selector_assertions.rb:299:in `assert_select'
    ~/foo/test/functional/api/keywords_controller_test.rb:123:in `test_html'
```

I know that I can use `assert_match %q{<h2>#{language.upcase}</h2>}` in my block, but that feels so crufty when `assert_select` exists.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a hacktacular solution (thanks to the [HTML::Tag class in scrapi](http://www.quarkruby.com/2007/8/28/html-tag-class-in-scrapi) post on the QuarkRuby blog), using the undocumented `HTML::Tag` class that is yielded by `assert_select` in block form:

```
# Count the <h2> tags and accumulate their text content
h2_texts = nil
assert_select('body > h2', :count => languages.size) do |elements|
   h2_texts = elements.map {|element| element.children.first.content }
end
languages.each do |language|
  assert h2_texts.include?(language.upcase), "<h2> tag for #{language} exists"
end
```

I guess `assert_select` just can't do this, or it can and it is not documented. I guess I'll have to [UTSL](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/UTSL)...